# How to write query to query data between start datetime and end datetime

Tags: mysql

Hi guys i have to query like, in database for some start_datetime and end_datetime assume that there will be table with the name test and the columns are className ,startDateTime and endDateTime

example data  classname ="I" startDateTime='2017-04-18 08:00:00' and  endDateTime='2017-04-18 09:00:00'

**My query is like if i value like below it should not fetch the example data**

startDateTime=2017-04-18 07:00:00"" and endDateTime="2017-04-18 07:55:00"

startDateTime=2017-04-18 10:00:00"" and endDateTime="2017-04-18 11:00:00"

startDateTime=2017-04-19 08:00:00"" and endDateTime="2017-04-19 09:00:00"

**it should fetch the example data**

startDateTime=2017-04-18 08:00:00"" and endDateTime="2017-04-18 09:00:00"

startDateTime=2017-04-18 08:10:00"" and endDateTime="2017-04-18 08:55:00"

startDateTime=2017-04-18 08:30:00"" and endDateTime="2017-04-18 09:30:00"

```
 SELECT * FROM timetable_tbl  WHERE className='I' and 
    ((StartDate>='startDateTimeValue' and StartDate<'startDateTimeValue') or
    (StartDate<='startDateTimeValue' and StartDate<'startDateTimeValue') or
    (StartDate>='startDateTimeValue' and EndDate<='endDateTimeValue'));
```

Comment: In the table, the start  and end dates both are 12:00:00. So why should it display the record if you are querying for between 12:10 to 12:30?

Comment: sorry,i have changed now

Comment: So the thing is.. you are querying on 2 fields with 'AND'. So it means, it will show the records those have start date greater or equal to 12:10 AND end_date less than or equal to 12:30. So both condition should match in order to get result. But the existing record does not match with the first condition I.e. start_date is not greater than or equal to 12:10

Answer (score 1):

the below logic satisfy my all above criteria

```
((startDate>? And endDate<? ) or (startDate>=? And endDate<=? ) or (startDate<? And endDate>? ) or (startDate<? And endDate>? ))
```